# How do I change the font size of the \tag content globally?

Tags: align, fontsize

Is it possible to set the font size for the `\tag{}` content from the `align` environment globally?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
1+1=2 \tag{test}  
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

I want the tag text to be `\small` without having to specify it every time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can patch `\maketag@@@` with the help of `\patchcmd` from `etoolbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\maketag@@@}{\normalfont}{\normalfont\tiny}{}{}   %% Change \tiny to \small
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
1+1=2 \tag{test}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this works, ty. I assume nobody does change the size of tags since you need to patch the original command...

Answer (score 1):

If you are inserting `\tag` manually, why not to define, say, `\Tag` in the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\Tag}[1]{\tag{\small #1\normalsize}}

\begin{align*}
1+1=2 \tag{test}  
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
1+1=2 \Tag{test}  
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this too but if you look closer or set, say, scriptsize you'll notice that the first parentheses is still at normal size

Comment: @BeeGirl You are right. I forgot changing to normal size. And your parentheses should be at normal size or also small?

Comment: to make this work you need something like `\newcommand{\Tag}[1]{\tag*{\footnotesize(#1)}}`. But seemed like a hack to me (well, the other answer is too :P)

Comment: @BeeGirl I thought that the main problem is reamaining normalsize parentheses and small entry. As I induce from the accepted answer, they should also be small.

Comment: Yes, that was it. Anyway with your code the second p. does scale to `\small`. It's only the first that does not. It should have something to do with the definition of `\tag`, dunno.

Comment: @BeeGirl Please see the corrected version. I forgot to change back to the normal font earlier.